# How can I set max width and height on UIImageView while maintaining 1:1 ratio?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uistoryboard, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to do this in storyboard but can't seem to figure it out. I have a QR code (square UIImageView) centered (vertically and horizontally) in another UIView that I want to expand a bit depending on phone size, but I don't want it to go over 150x150 otherwise it looks odd. Here is what I tried. Any help greatly appreciated.

[image: Attempt]

Comment: What is the issue that you are currently facing?

Comment: @AravindAR it appears to be invalid constraint combination (it turns red in storyboard indicating something is wrong).

Comment: So then try removing either Height <= 150 or width<= 150 constraint and see if it works

Comment: The problem is I need some kind of size constraint because otherwise it may grow too large and look weird on some devices.

Comment: Yup you are already setting the aspect ratio to 1:1 so either Height <= 150 or width<= 150 will be needed and not both

Comment: I just removed the width constraint completely and it is still messed up =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to:

- Center it in its superview
- Keep 1:1 aspect ratio
- Keep it less-than-or-equal-to 150x150

So, centering is obvious (yay, auto layout). 1:1 ratio is also easy. The Trick is:

Pin all 4 sides to the superview sides at `>= 0`.

Set the `Width <= 150`.

And then ---

Set ***another*** `Width` constraint, this time `Width Equals: 150` but with `Priority` of *less-than* `1000`. I used `999` and it did the job.

[image]

Pinning the sides and top/bottom with `>= 0` gets it to shrink when the superview is smaller than 150 (in either direction).

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this for a long time.

```
(UIImage*) scaleImage:(UIImage*)image toSize:(CGSize)newSize {
CGSize scaledSize = newSize;
float scaleFactor = 1.0;
if( image.size.width > image.size.height ) {
    scaleFactor = image.size.width / image.size.height;
    scaledSize.width = newSize.width;
    scaledSize.height = newSize.height / scaleFactor;
}
else {
    scaleFactor = image.size.height / image.size.width;
    scaledSize.height = newSize.height;
    scaledSize.width = newSize.width / scaleFactor;
}

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions( scaledSize, NO, 0.0 );
CGRect scaledImageRect = CGRectMake( 0.0, 0.0, scaledSize.width, 
scaledSize.height );
[image drawInRect:scaledImageRect];
UIImage* scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    

return scaledImage;
}
```